# Is there cheap or free drawing application which has brush with self-improoving brush-stroke

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drawing, graphic-design, animation

I've seen such in Clip Studio Paint (ex Manga Studio). There is brush that makes such strokes that when you made a stroke it's shape became better: it became more smooth and tips became sharp. It may be raster or vector - doesn't matter. It's called "For effect brush".
Is there something free of cheaper that Clip Studio ?
I would appreciate recommendations both for Linux and Windows.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make strokes pointy? Or just smoother?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul I edited question, though why then I posted image if I have to explain that by words, for beauty ? ) Do you have certain application on your mind ?

Comment: For searchability.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Krita](https://krita.org) is a good option.

Krita is a professional FREE and open source painting program, and has Brush Stabilizers.

It's available for Linux, Windows and Mac.

You could see the full features in https://krita.org/en/features/highlights/

Comment: I forgot to say that is available for Linux, Windows and Mac. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you, didn't know Krita has such tool, similar, thought not as good as what Clip Stuio has.